# Executing Java program through Command Line (Windows) vs Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, jar

I have a java program which is located in the /workspace folder. Under the /workspace folder I have a /src/appFolder which contains 15 .java files and /lib which contains 19 .jar files which I included in Eclipse.

I can run the program seamlessly using Eclipse but I can't get it to run in Command Line. I am trying to compline using javac and have exhausted existing Stackoverflow suggestions. Essenstially, I need to know how do I compile the program using javac? At the moment I get an error saying *package* (which is .jar files) is missing. How do I include the 19 jars contained in the /workspace/lib so javac *.java complies before I run the program using java myApp.java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

java supports `*`, but note that your shell (bash or cmd.exd or whatnot) *also* does, so you need to put in some effort to tell the shell **not** to:

```bash
javac -cp 'lib/*' my/pkg/*.java
java -cp 'lib/*:.' my.pkg.Main
```

Will do it on all normal (posix) OS. If you are on windows, use linux subsystem for windows. If you can't do that, I'm not sure how to do it - possibly just `java -cp "lib/*;." my.pkg.Main` (note, semicolon and double quotes. That's not a typo!)

If your code is in more than one package, you'll have to list them all by hand.

Generally your average java programmer **does not ever** invoke `javac`. They use a build system like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Follow the link, tutorials aplenty.

Answer (score -1):

Behind the scene, Eclipse or IntelliJ or any IDE, it also run the java command to compile, build and run your java project.

Read more about `classpath` in java. It is the option to include the jar files that used in your code.

for example: `javac --classpath external_libs\lib1.jar;other\lib2.jar;`

You can also see for yourself how eclipse run it:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Considering I have 19 jars, does this mean I have to include them all by name individually or is there a * option to magically include the folder with them all?

Comment: Yes, you can totally just point to the folder containing all the jar files instead of listing all 19 jar file names